# Output to screen in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, line, database, dbms-output

I have searched quite extensively on how to output messages in Oracle SQL. I have read a lot about dbms_output.put_line and dbms_output.get_line and tried using both but am unable to get either to work. Using Oracle SQL Developer Version 2.

Comment: Oracle 2 was [released in 1979](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_database#Corporate.2Ftechnical_timeline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what application you're using, but, in general, to output the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer to your client, you first need to issue a `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`.

See http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/serveroutput.html.

Comment: sorry I meant Oracle SQL Developer version 2